# Files referenced in ASPX-page don't cause invokation of Application_BeginRequest

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

When I reload a page called *Donkey.aspx*, there's a breakpoint being hit on the method below.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (application.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith(".blopp")) { ... }
}
```

The problem is that all I get to see is a hit on the *Donkey.aspx* and another file (the one with id *__browserLink_initializationData*) referenced by it, only. However, there's a bunch of other references to files and those are not causing hits on the method. The end of the produced page looks like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="beep.blopp" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="typeahead.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="utils.js"></script>
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" 
       id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="54ACFC5B" />
</div>
</form>

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
{"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"f51b45a6ac174b6e8880184492a80734"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:64593/9...7/browserLink" async="async">
</script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->
</body>
```

Accessing another page gives me the expected behavior, namely a bunch of hits on the event handler above, including CSS-files etc. Notable is that the files **do indeed** get loaded, as verified by the functionality of the scripts, console status codes (200 and 304 all around). The master page is virtually empty.

I'm at loss on what's wrong and even more uncertain on how to trouble-shoot it.

Answer (score 1):

Static files are usually cached by browser. Turn off browser cache or reload all from server (Ctrl+F5).

Comment: Yeah, true. But that doesn't explain why the *Application_BeginRequest* method doesn't get invoked for them, does it? Also, I'm not in the position to make the users reload. Is there a way to enforce a reload of them programmatically?

Comment: Add your beep.blopp from script  

    <script>  
      var sc=document.createElement('script');  
      sc.src='beep.blopp?refresh='+Math.random();  
      document.head.appendChild(sc);  
   </script>  

In this case the request will be always "new".

Comment: Just as you predicted, the status code of the file is now 200 - brand new resource to be delivered. However, there's still this weirdness - fetching the file seems not to trigger *Application_BeginRequest* anyway. It breaks on fetching the *ASPX* file and the *browserLink*, whatever that is but no other files! Checking other applications seems to break on hitting every file referrenced but in **this particular** project, no such reaction. I'm not very skilled in WebForms and I strongly suspect that it's setting or some code missing. No idea what that might be, though...

Comment: Usually static files are served by IIS (or whatever Web server you have) without participation of .NET. If possible, rename your beep.blopp to beep.aspx to hit Global.asax.